# How to recover a messed-up git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I `git submodule add`'ed a submodule at a wrong directory.
I `git rm`'ed the submodule and then `git submodule summary` returned `fatal: Not a git repository: '<path to the deleted submodule>.git'`.

I used `grep -r '<path to the deleted submodule>'` to remove all references to the deleted directory.
There was only one reference left to the deleted directory, which was in `.git/index` (binary file).
But `git submodule summary` still gives `fatal: Not a git repository: '<path to the deleted submodule>.git'`.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check:

- the content of your .gitmodules file
- the content of .git/modules subfolder

If you remove any reference of the submodule you git rm'ed, that should be better.

Also, make sure you try again a `git rm mysubmodule`, *without* any trailing slash.